# How Can I Use [ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1] in Terminal using AppleScript

Tags: macos, terminal, grep, applescript, ifconfig

I'm new to AppleScript. I am trying small projects and improve on my knowledge for bigger projects.

My attempt is to extract specific network info using ifconfig. I've tried this, but returns

> "Expected end of line but found identifier."

Then "inet" is highlighted. Removing "" from inet shows more lines than I want. What's the syntax for multiple commands within a command?

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate
delay 2
tell application "System Events" to tell "Terminal"
    keystroke "ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1"
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that quotes don't nest. When you use this:

```
"ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1"
```

...that's two double-quoted strings, `"ifconfig | grep "` and `" | grep -v 127.0.0.1"`, with some weird `inet`  thing between them. To include double-quotes in a double-quoted string, you need to escape them:

```
"ifconfig | grep \"inet \" | grep -v 127.0.0.1"
```

The second problem is that Terminal doesn't accept keystrokes directly, so you'd need to leave off the `...to tell "Terminal"` part. But I'd recommend using `do shell script` instead of trying to control the Terminal application:

```
set IPinfo to (do shell script "ifconfig | grep \"inet \" | grep -v 127.0.0.1")
```

(The parentheses are not needed here, but I prefer to include them for readability.)

Comment: Re: @Gordon Davisson: "The second problem is that keystroke sends key codes, not strings."  Why so?  **The  keystroke command sends strings.** The second problem of OP's script is that the script should tell only to System events to keystroke the string: **tell application "System Events" to  keystroke "ifconfig | grep \"inet\" | grep -v 127.0.0.1"**

Comment: @RobertKniazidis You're right, I misinterpreted the cause of the error I was getting -- apparently Terminal just doesn't accept the `keystroke` command, it has to be sent to System Events instead. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will do what you are trying to do:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'"
end tell
```